# Calculating distance

Tags: geometry

> EC=GD
>
> ABCD=Square with length a
>
> Searching DH

How do I calculate DH in the most simplific way?

I tried to do it with functions and point D as the 2d origin. But I feel that is not the best way.

Could someone give me a hint in the right direction?

My attempt

squarelength=a

EC=y

GD=b

g=straight through E and D

h=straight through G and A

$D=(0,0)$

$g(x)=mx+d$

$g(0)=0$

$EC=e$

$g(a)=e=m\times a+d$

$d$ is 0 (since it goes through (0,0))

$m=\frac{g(a)-0}{a-0}=\frac{y}{a}$

> $g(x)=\frac{y}{a}* x$

$h(x)=m*x+d$

$h(0)=-a$

therefore $d=-a$

$h(-b)=0$

$m=\frac{0-(-a)}{-b-0}=\frac{a}{-b}=-\frac{a}{b}$

> $h(x)=-\frac{a}{b}*x-a$

Now calculating where g and h meet.

$g(x)=h(x)$

$\frac{y}{a}* x=-\frac{a}{b}*x-a$

$x=\frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}}$

Now getting the coordinates:

$g(\frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}})=\frac{y}{a}* \frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}}$

Therefore the two straights meet at $(\frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}},\frac{y}{a}* \frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}})$

Now getting the distance from the origin (=DH)

$DH=\sqrt{(\frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}})^2+(\frac{y}{a}* \frac{-a}{\frac{y}{a}+\frac{a}{b}})^2}$

Is this right?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to include your workings from your attempt, whether even if there is perhaps a better way.

Comment: @amWhy ok i do.

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. . . . Could you try to clean it up some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $EC =b$ then:

Let $C(0,0)$ and $D(-a,0)$ and $E(0,b)$, then $G(-a-b,0)$, $B(0,-a)$ and $A(-a,-a)$.

Line $DE$ has equation: $${x\over -a}+{y\over b} =1 \implies y={b\over a}x+b $$ and line $AG$ has equation: $$y=-{a\over b}(x+a+b)$$

So we have $$x_H=-{a^3+a^2b+ab^2\over a^2+b^2}  $$
so $$y_H=-{ab^2\over a^2+b^2}  $$

Then $$HD ={ab\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: is it standard notation to write HD instead of DH? is your origin chosen randomly or is there an argument for C=(0,0)?

Comment: It seem that if I choose $C$ as origin it will be the smallest number of computation. And it is no difference if you write HD or DH

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Show that $\Delta DCE$ is similar to $\Delta DHG$. In order to show this, show that the line $EH$ is perpendicular to the line $GA$.

Hint 2: By similarity, the following ratios of lengths of the sides holds:
$$ \frac{|HD|}{|GD|} = \frac{|DC|}{|DE|}.$$
Note that $|DE|$ can be expressed in terms of $|DC|$ (which equal tot $a$) and $|CE|$ (which is the same as $|GD|$).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\triangle ADH\sim\triangle EDC$ as $m\angle ECD = m\angle DHA$ since they are right angles, and $m\angle ADH = m\angle DEC$ since $$m\angle HDE = 180^\circ = m\angle HDA + m\angle EDC + 90^\circ\to m\angle HDA + m\angle EDC = 90^\circ$$

So, by CPCTC, $$\frac a{\overline{ED}} = \frac{\overline{AH}}a\to a^2 = \overline{AH}\cdot\overline{ED}$$

Through similar logic, we find $\triangle GDA\sim\triangle EDC$. However, we also know that $\overline{DA}=\overline{DC}$, hence $\triangle GDA\equiv\triangle EDC$. Hence, $$\overline{GD}=\overline{EC}=\frac{a^2}{\overline{AH}}$$

Finally, we can also show $\triangle GHD\sim\triangle ECD$. You can finish the proof from here.